# GeoIP Extension not working for Store Views

Tags: magento2.3, magento-community, geoip

I have installed Mageworx Geo Lock Free via SSH method & configured using the provided instructions.
https://support.mageworx.com/genext/install_m2/
https://support.mageworx.com/manuals/free/geolock/

I have used the following commands

```
php bin/magento module:enable MageWorx_GeoLock

php bin/magento module:enable MageWorx_GeoIP

php bin/magento setup:upgrade

php bin/magento cache:flush

php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

php bin/magento module:enable MageWorx_GeoLock

php bin/magento setup:upgrade

php bin/magento cache:flush

php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

I'm getting the Mageworx settings in Configuration and have set my US store to deny India and for my India store, I have set rule deny US country.
I have also updated the GeoIP database.

However, both stores get shown for both countries

Pl. help if anyone has used this.

[image: GeoIP DB Updated]
[image: India Store settings]
[image: US Store settings]

Answer (score 0):

After followup with their support over more than 2 weeks, they stated that, their extension will work only if the StoreView urls are different.
 It won't work if StoreViews share same URL.